# How to apply .OR in joi validation

Tags: npm, json-schema-validator, joi

Well, i have the following Joi object, im trying to use Or method, as you see i have two objects contains phone i wanted to use Or method but i got failed

```
body: Joi.object().keys({
            member: Joi.object().required().keys({
                id: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string().max(30),
                email: Joi.string().required().max(255)
            }),
            billingAddress: Joi.object().keys({
                line1: Joi.string().required(),
                line2: Joi.string().max(60),
                city: Joi.string().required().max(50),
                state: Jio.required(),
                postalCode: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string().max(15)
            })
}).or('member.phone','billingAddress.phone')
```

what im trying to do is i need a phone either to be in **member.phone** or in **billingAddress.phone** at least one of them is exist 
the code above is not working What should i do ?

Comment: This has recently been addressed in [v14](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1615). Check what version you're using and consider upgrading if you're < 14.

Comment: @Ankh May you post it as answer ?
i really don't want to remove the question however, there are a lot of developers still using the old version, at least who was working on it since long time and they didn't upgrade 
it works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're attempting to use has only recently gone into version [14.0.0](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1615) of Joi so the first step is to ensure you're requiring at least v14 of Joi.

> Nested paths on object.or/nand/and/xor/with/without()
>
> Nested paths on those functions are now supported. I consider this a breaking change as you may (but you really really shouldn't) have used dotted paths in those validations because you wanted to check dotted properties. If that's your case there is currently no migration path but we can discuss that in an issue.

For older versions it would require either a messy combination of `.when()` or `.alternatives()`, a custom validator or manually written logic with multiple schemas.